# How to make a set of lists

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list of lists like this:

```
i = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5]]
```

I would like to get a list containing "unique" lists (based on their elements) like:

```
o = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5]]
```

I cannot use `set()` as there are non-hashable elements in the list. Instead, I am doing this:

```
o = []
for e in i:
  if e not in o:
    o.append(e)
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: An unrelated question, but why is this possible in other languages like Java?

Comment: I guess it is allowed because every object in Java implements its hashcode and equals method (via Java base Object class or overridden methods) and thus can be a key in a map. But even in Java, having mutable structures like Lists or Sets as keys would be a bad idea. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9973694/5065946

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can create a set of tuples, a set of lists will not be possible because of non hashable elements as you mentioned.

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5]]
>>> set(tuple(i) for i in l)
{(1, 2, 3), (2, 4, 5)}
```

Comment: or `{tuple(i) for i in l}`

Comment: @wim +1, though I find the `set` more intuitive; most of the times I see a `{`, I'm thinking a dictionary :)

Comment: Just to clarify: set of tuples of unhashable types, like `set(([], {}))` won't work either.

Comment: or `set(map(tuple, l))`

Comment: @wim what is that syntax? Is it a set comprehension?

Comment: @wim first time I see this syntax, where does it come from, it returns a set, but how come?

Comment: @Phani correct, that's a set comprehension.  a little bit more efficient than the solution in the answer, which has overhead of a function call and a generator expression.

Answer (score 7):

```
i = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5]]

print([ele for ind, ele in enumerate(i) if ele not in i[:ind]])
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5]]
```

If you consider `[2, 4, 5]` to be equal to `[2, 5, 4]` then you will need to do further checks

Comment: sets are almost always the way to go but sometimes things cannot be hashed

Comment: yeah, we can we use this approach, when we have a list of list of lists in which case we can't use tuples.

Comment: @Apero, I don't think it should matter

Answer (score 6):

You can convert each element to a tuple and then insert it in a set.

Here's some code with your example:

```
tmp = set()
a = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5]]
for i in a:
    tmp.add(tuple(i))
```

`tmp` will be like this:

```
{(1, 2, 3), (2, 4, 5)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it:

```
I = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5]]
mySet = set()

for j in range(len(I)):
  mySet = mySet | set([tuple(I[j])])

print(mySet)
```