# Type error while comparing two dictionaries

Tags: python

I have following two dictionaries

```
x = {0:[1,2,3], 1:[1,2,3], 2:[1,2,3]}
y = {0:[1,2,3], 1:[1,2,3], 2:[1,2,3]}
```

I need to check the similarity of these two dictionaries. I am using following code for that

```
shared_items = set(x.items()) & set(y.items())
```

But it gives me

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` error.

What is the reason for this issue and how to correct it.

Comment: print x==y will do fine

Answer (score 5):

A `set` cannot contain a non-hashable object as it uses hashes for item lookup. Since you have `list` values, which are mutable, adding those in a `set` raises an error.

You will need to use `tuple` values instead.

```
x = {1: (1, 2, 3), 2: (1, 2, 3)}
y = {0: (1, 2, 3), 1: (1, 2, 3)}

shared_items = set(x.items()) & set(y.items())
# shared_items: {(1, (1, 2, 3))}
```

Although, since values in a `dict` are allowed to be mutable, you might want to settle for another data structure for a more general solution. The following will return a `dict` of the shared key-value pairs.

```
x = {1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [1, 2, 3]}
y = {0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [1, 2, 3]}

shared_items = {k: x[k] for k in x if k in y and x[k] == y[k]}
# shared_items: {1: [1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 2):

It unfortunately won't work in `Python3x`, since a list is considered unhashable in the same. How about just comparing them directly, this should work for most scenarios.

```
x == y
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly compare dictionnaries with `==`:

```
In [1]: x = {0:[1,2,3], 1:[1,2,3], 2:[1,2,3]}

In [2]: y = {0:[1,2,3], 1:[1,2,3], 2:[1,2,3]}

In [3]: shared_items = x == y

In [4]: shared_items
Out[4]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a set of lists. Lists are "unhashable", and essentially no mutable objects are ([more info here](https://blog.m157q.tw/posts/2013/06/05/python-mutable-vs-hashable/)). If you want to do something similar, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783326/how-to-make-a-set-of-lists).