# New to Python, i am Missing an Output. goal is to find all possible outcomes from a list that sums to Zero

Tags: python

Problem: From a given list, i should return all possible outcomes that give a sum of 0
for a list `[-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]` the output should be `[[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1]]`

The problem is it's not showing all possible outcomes.

**Code:**

```
nums = [-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]
def three_sum():
  lst=[]
  for i in nums:             #take 3 variables
    for j in nums:
      for k in nums:
        if (nums.index(i) != nums.index(j)) and (nums.index(i) != nums.index(k)) and (nums.index(j) != nums.index(k)): 
          if i+j+k==0:
            tmp_lst=[i,j,k]
            tmp_lst.sort()
            lst.append(tmp_lst)
  for m in lst:
    while lst.count(m)>1:
      lst.remove(m)
      lst.sort()
  return lst
```

The **expected output** should be `[[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1]]` but i get `[[-1, 0, 1]]`

Comment: Does the length have to be 3? Why not `[0]` or `[1,-1]`, etc

Comment: The function is called `three_sum` so I think it is a constraint on the problem which was not mentioned explicitly

Comment: That is a safe _assumption_ but asking for clarification is what comments are for.

Comment: Yes i forgot to mention in the description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when you check `(nums.index(i) != nums.index(j)) and (nums.index(i) != nums.index(k)) and (nums.index(j) != nums.index(k))`, if you have two equal numbers in the list (like two `-1`) then `nums.index` will return the index of the first one and you will discard that combination.

To solve this I changed your `i`, `j` and `k` to be the indexes and force them to not be equal directly in the range function.

```py
nums = [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]


def three_sum(nums):
    lst = []
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(nums)):
            for k in range(j + 1, len(nums)):
                n1, n2, n3 = nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]
                if n1 + n2 + n3 == 0:
                    tmp_lst = [n1, n2, n3]
                    tmp_lst.sort()
                    lst.append(tmp_lst)

    # remove possible duplicates
    for m in lst:
        while lst.count(m) > 1:
            lst.remove(m)
            lst.sort()

    return lst


print(three_sum(nums))
```

Answer (score 5):

Not an answer to your question, but here's an alternative solution using `itertools`. The nice thing about it is that you can use it to get any combination size

```
import itertools

def n_sum(nums, n=3):
    results = set()
    for c in itertools.combinations(nums, n):
        if sum(c) == 0:
            results.add(tuple(sorted(c)))
    return results

print(n_sum([-1,0,1,2,-1,-4], 3))
```

Output

```
{(-1, -1, 2), (-1, 0, 1)}
```

Or if you prefer a shorter version:

```
def n_sum(nums, n):
    return {tuple(sorted(c)) for c in itertools.combinations(nums, n) if sum(c) == 0}
```

Comment: Very good code, excellent use of `itertools`and also the proper data structures (tuples for the combinations and a set to eliminate duplicates)

Comment: here `results.add(tuple(sorted(c)))` why did you use tuple and thanks for introducing me to itertools.

Comment: You can't make a `set` of `lists`. [How to make a set of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26783343)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp 
c is a tuple how can we `sum(c)` TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Comment: @Mourya `sum` works on tuples. I don't get any errors with this code. What are you passing to the function? https://replit.com/@JohnnyMopp/SandybrownConcreteBrace#main.py

Comment: @JohnnyMopp i sincerely apologize, i was trying to test the code and mistakenly put out a wrong input i.e. [[1,0,-1],[-1,2,-1]]