# Best way to map multiple determinants to a value in Java

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

I have a requirement in which I need to map multiple determinants to values.

- Each set of determinants in a given job execution is guaranteed to be unique. The value to be determined doesn't have to be unique but it probably is.
- Depending on the input to the job execution, this could be either one key, or the combination of two keys, or the combination of `n` keys that will be mapped to a single value. In practice this `n` will probably be limited to no more than 5, although it is possible it could exceed that.
- Each job execution will have a set number of determinants for all inputs (I.e., all inputs will have either 2 determinants, 3 determinants, or n determinants, and will not have a mix).

One key example: `foo --> bar`

Two keys: `foo, bar --> baz`

Three keys: `foo, bar, baz --> hai`

Prior to this, the requirement was that I would only ever map two values to another value. I created an immutable Key class with two member variables and the appropriate override of `equals` and `hashCode`.

```
public class Key {
    String determinant0;
    String determinant1;
    public Key(String d0, d1) {
        determinant0 = d0;
        determinant1 = d1;
    }
    // ..
}
```

However, now that I may be dealing with n number of values, I want to take a look at using a list as the key.

```
Map<List, String> map = new HashMap<List, String>();
map.put(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz"), "hai");
String determined = map.get(Arrays.AsList("foo","bar","baz"));
assert (determined.equals("hai"));
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973596/arraylist-as-key-in-hashmap) reminds me that it is bad to use a mutable object (like a List) as a key in a map. However, in my application, the key is only set once and is never altered. Here is an alternative from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16839191/1391717) that forces it to be immutable:

```
HashMap<List<String>, String> map;

map.put(
    // unmodifiable so key cannot change hash code
    Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz")),
    "hai"
);
```

In addition, I could always make a class like the following to prevent mutations on the list:

```
public class Key {
    List<String> determinants;
    public Key(List<String> determinants) {
        this.determinants = determinants
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        //...
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //...
    }
}

Key key = new Key(Arrays.asList("foo","bar","baz"));
```

Using a plain array as the key won't work, because an array's equal method only checks for identity:

```
Map<String[], String> map = new HashMap<String[], String>();
String[] key = new String[]{"foo", "bar", "baz"}
map.put(key, "hai");
System.out.println(map.get(key)); // null
```

That could be fixed by the following:

```
public class Key {
    String[] determinants;
    public Key(String... determinants) {
        this.determinants = determinants;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        //...
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //...
    }
}
```

How about concatting all the determinants together in a string?

```
public class Key {
    String hash = "";
    public Key(String... determinants) {
        for (String determinant : determinants) {
            hash += determinant + "_";
        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        //...
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Which one of these solutions (or another one that I did not propose) is the best suited for these requirements?

Comment: Side note: a 0-arg list is perfectly valid for a `...` argument.

Comment: I think you should just have different keys in your hashmap with same value. Instead of searching O(n)^2 with a list inside of a list. That is if you search the keys for a key and then use that key with multiple array to search for value

Comment: Is the order of the keys significant? If not, then a `List` does not model your problem very well.

Comment: John makes a good point, if the order in which the keys come doesn't matter don't store the key as a Collection of any kind.

Comment: @YaWang if the order doesn't matter, I think a set collection would be preferable, right? What do you mean by "don't store the key as a collection of any kind" ?

Comment: If the order doesn't matter *and* duplicate keys are not meaningful then a `Set` could work.  The `Set` interface defines contents-based requirements for `equals()` and `hashCode()` that all implementations are supposed to support.

Comment: Well how are you inputting you key in your program? You would have to input an array of some kind if you want your key to be a collection of sorts. How are you getting string array for your key? Is it in another list?

Comment: @YaWang At run time, the job would load a json array into memory from Mongo containing a list of objects, like `[{"a": "foo", "b": "bar", "c": "baz", "determinant": "hai"}, ...]` (It could also load it from a RDBMS with those four columns). The job would then load this into a data structure like I am proposing, so it would know to map the `(foo, bar, baz) --> hai`. The job then iterates over a CSV file containing the data I want to analyze, with the columns A, B, and C.

Comment: `raise` is not a keyword in Java. Are you an Ada programmer ? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a comment, your question includes too much details and could have been way shorter. Now comes my answer.

I prefer using a wrapper class that completely hides the representation of the class. One thing you can do as a small optimization is storing the hashCode of your keys to prevent computing it every time. The `equals` method will be called more rarely (each collision in the map) and you can't do much about it :

```
public class Key {
    private String[] determinants;
    private int hashCode;

    public Key(String... determinants) {
        if (determinants == null || determinants.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please provide at least one value");
        }
        this.determinants = determinants;
        this.hashCode = Objects.hash(determinants);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Key)) return false;
        Key that = (Key) o;
        return Arrays.equals(determinants, that.determinants);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```