# Assigning an ArrayList a color

Tags: java, arraylist, colors

```
    ArrayList<Integer> initgenome = new ArrayList<>(5000);
    initgenome.addAll(Collections.nCopies(10, 1));
    initgenome.addAll(Collections.nCopies(4990, 0));

    ArrayList<Integer> genometwo = new ArrayList<>(5000);
    genometwo.addAll(Collections.nCopies(10, 2));
    genometwo.addAll(Collections.nCopies(4990, 0));

    ArrayList<Integer> genomethree = new ArrayList<>(5000);
    genomethree.addAll(Collections.nCopies(10, 3));
    genomethree.addAll(Collections.nCopies(4990, 0));

    ArrayList<Integer> genomefour = new ArrayList<>(5000);
    genomefour.addAll(Collections.nCopies(10, 4));
    genomefour.addAll(Collections.nCopies(4990, 0));
```

I am doing a project in Eclipse using Java and I have my objects randomly picking one of these genomes when initializing. I was curious if there was anyway to set a color to a each arraylist so you could visually see the genome that got picked? Thanks!

Comment: How do you expect to _see_ the color? On the screen?

Comment: When the program is run, there is a grid that pops up with my microbes on the grid. Right now, they are all blue.

Comment: What GUI toolkit do you use? Swing, JavaFX?

Comment: I believe I am using AWT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a mapping (`Map`):

```
Map<ArrayList<Integer>, String> genomesToColors = new HashMap<>();
genomesToColors.add(initgenome, "red");
genomesToColors.add(genometwo, "blue");
genomesToColors.add(genomethree, "green");
genomesToColors.add(genomefour, "purple");
```

Then after you have picked your `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> genome = // however you do it.
String color = genomesToColors.get(genome);
```

Since your idea of a genome is getting more complex, you may want to create a `Genome` class. You can give it a `sequence` attribute and a `color` attribute.

```
public class Genome {

   public List<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   public String color;

   // Getters, setters, whatever you want.

}
```

EDIT: Since your genome may mutate, I would suggest going with the class based solution. It is more easily extensible, and takes advantage of OOP.

Comment: Having mutable object as a map key is generally a bad idea.

Comment: True, if the genome is being modified (mutated?) in anyway, the class based solution is probably better. If the genomes are not mutating, an immutable list should be used. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973596/arraylist-as-key-in-hashmap

Comment: The genome is able to mutate.