# TreeMap<int[],Double> initialisation and sorting by value

Tags: java, sorting, treemap

I have to make sorted map which key is int[] and value is double. It cant be swapped because double will be duplicated. Moreover, map will be sort by value and last x values will be deleted.

I tried to make

```
Map<int[],Double> map = new TreeMap<>();;
int[] i = {0,1,1,0};  
    map.put(i,8.5);  // ERROR HERE Organisms.java:46
    i = new int[]{0,0,0,0};
    map.put(i,30.0);
    System.out.println("sorted" + sortByValue(map));
```

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   [I cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable     at
>   java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1294)  at
>   java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:538)   at
>   com.pszt_organism.Organisms.test(Organisms.java:46) **<-- MARKED ERROR**

I found method `sortByValue(Map<K, V> map)` in this topic: [java8 example by Carter Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values-java)

I suppose that TreeMap has problem with sorting table of int. How to solve that?

EDIT:

```
private  <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> sortByValue(Map<K, V> map) {
        return map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(/*Collections.reverseOrder()*/))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                        (e1, e2) -> e1,
                        LinkedHashMap::new
                ));
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share your implementation of sortByValue function

Comment: You need to wrap your `int[]` into a class which implements `Comparable ` as well as `hashcode()`, and  `equals()` methods

Comment: If you want it sorted by value, then why bother with a map implementation that sorts by key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `TreeMap` to use that sorting method. Just use a different `Map`. That sorting method creates a new `LinkedHashMap` for the result, so the `Map` which is passed as an argument is just a temporary container.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Java array types do not implement `Comparable`.

The solution: implement a `Comparator` that will compare your `int[]` keys, and pass an instance as a parameter to the `TreeMap` constructor.

However, this will only work if the `int[]` objects are not mutated while they are in use as keys.  If you mutate them, then you will "break" the `TreeMap` and `Map` operations will behave incorrectly.

You could also wrap the `int[]` objects in a class that implements `Comparable`, implement `compareTo`, `equals` and `hashCode`.  The same caveat about mutation applies with this approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

`int[]` arrays as poorly suited for use as keys in a `Map` (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9973694/335858) for a brief explanation; it talks about array lists, but the same logic applies to arrays as well).

If you are set on using arrays as keys anyway, proceed with caution:

Since `int[]` is not `Comparable`, you cannot use it as a key without supplying a piece of logic for comparing arrays.

Here is how you can do it:

```
Map<int[],Double> map = new TreeMap<>(
    new Comparator<int[]>() {
        @Override public int compare(int[] lhs, int[] rhs) {
            int len = Math.min(lhs.length, rhs.length);
            for (int i = 0 ; i != len ; i++) {
                if (lhs[i] != rhs[i]) {
                    return Integer.compare(lhs[i], rhs[i]);
                }
            }
            // If we're here, common elements match up;
            // hence, the longer of the two arrays wins.
            return Integer.compare(lhs.length, rhs.length)
        }           
    }
);
```

Comment: This, except you should just keep a final static comparator and pass it on. Slightly more permanent memory usage, a lot less allocation.